# DeprecationWarning: '_reque st_ctx_stack' is deprecated and will be removed in Flask 2.3

Tags: python, flask, pytest, flask-jwt-extended

I am running pytest in flask and getting following deprecation warning:
the application is pretty simple using `flask_jwt_extended` for authentication.

```
\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_jwt_extended\view_decorators.py:11: DeprecationWarning: '_reque
st_ctx_stack' is deprecated and will be removed in Flask 2.3.
from flask import _request_ctx_stack
```

Currently it is not affecting my application but should I take any steps to remediate this ?

Comment: Checking the flask changelog lead to the following https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/4682 I think in there should be a descritption on how to replace the deprecated context?

Answer (score 1):

the comment didn't point directly to the answer, at least for me. for me what works is documented [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/4682/files). `data:: _request_ctx_stack` is now `data:: flask.globals.request_ctx`. sample code now looks like

```py
from flask.globals import request_ctx

def get_request_details():
    ctx = request_ctx  # previously was _request_ctx_stack.top
    return {
        'request': "{} {} {}".format(
            ctx.request.method,
            ctx.request.url,
            ctx.request.environ.get('SERVER_PROTOCOL')
    }
```

hope that helps.